# My creator was kind of a jerk. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

Although my name normally means total failure
I was anything but
Flying high, I was initially a joke
But now I'm the standard for gold.

What am I?

Comment: Does this qualify for the [trivia] tag?

Comment: Definitely [current-events].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is

> "The Flop" (referring to the [Fosbury Flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fosbury_Flop))

Although my name normally means total failure

> A flop is usually synonymous with a failure

I was anything but

> This technique was actually very successful and Dick Fosbury used it to win in the 1968 Olympics.

Flying high, I was initially a joke

> It took a while for the technique to be adopted by experienced high jumpers. Many initially saw it as a joke.

But now I'm the standard for gold.

> Now every Olympic athlete uses this technique to try and win the gold medal.

Title

> Possibly linking the slang words 'dick' and 'jerk'. Not sure about this one.

Answer (score 1):

Although my name normally means total failure

> Icarus is a myth of a man who failed in flying

I was anything but

> Icarus is not a failure, he actually achieved some great things

Flying high, I was initially a joke

> Icarus  tried to fly to the Sun as a challenge

But now I'm the standard for gold.

> Icarus Gold you can buy online

---

or:

> JavaScript Garbage Collectors (fuzzy on the name = failure part)

Comment: Not the right answer. Sorry